# Crash error after system upgrade to Sierra Mac

Tags: macos

After upgrading from Mountain Lion to Sierra I get the crash report below on Launching the app.  Unfortunately, don't know what a Mach-0 error is.  I understand that some of the changes to the OS have killed much legacy software, but I was wondering if there might be an easy fix for this?

REPORT

```
Date/Time:             2016-11-13 10:12:45.737 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.1 (16B2555)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        B12B92D6-E58A-AE2F-ABD0-A1AC308EDE54

Sleep/Wake UUID:       46ADF4CD-C560-4953-B203-57A62C461FA4

Time Awake Since Boot: 11000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       670 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    EXEC, [0xc] This UPX compressed binary contains an invalid Mach-O header and cannot be loaded.

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9e066bb2 __posix_spawn + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9e061ef2 posix_spawn + 386
2   xpcproxy                        0x00000001098efd6d 0x1098ed000 + 11629
3   xpcproxy                        0x00000001098f098a 0x1098ed000 + 14730
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9df38255 start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000000000000d  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00007fff56312388  rdx: 0x00007fff563123a0
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00007f8f1c8010e5  rbp: 0x00007fff56312430  rsp: 0x00007fff56312388
   r8: 0x00007f8f1c600d90   r9: 0x00007f8f1c600d90  r10: 0x00007f8f1c402480  r11: 0x0000000000000202
  r12: 0x00007f8f1c402480  r13: 0x00007f8f1c8010e5  r14: 0x00007fff56312950  r15: 0x00007fff56312958
  rip: 0x00007fff9e066bb2  rfl: 0x0000000000000203  cr2: 0x00007fffa6c310a8

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x020000f4
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x1098ed000 -        0x1098f1fff  xpcproxy (2.0.0 - 972.20.3) <4A173B59-A786-3CBF-9740-CFC693060FEF> /usr/libexec/xpcproxy
       0x113adc000 -        0x113b19287  dyld (421.2) <13A9466A-2576-3ABB-AD9D-D6BC16439B8F> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff9c93d000 -     0x7fff9c93eff3  libSystem.B.dylib (1238) <CFC3669C-FB44-3A51-8815-1E84A168F3C5> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff9cab4000 -     0x7fff9cab4ff3  libauto.dylib (187) <5BBF6A00-CC76-389D-84E7-CA88EDADE683> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff9cad5000 -     0x7fff9cb2bff7  libc++.1.dylib (307.4) <BEE86868-F831-384C-919E-2B286ACFE87C> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff9cb2c000 -     0x7fff9cb56fff  libc++abi.dylib (307.2) <1CEF8ABB-7E6D-3C2F-8E0A-E7884478DD23> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff9d647000 -     0x7fff9da1c127  libobjc.A.dylib (706) <47104A1B-13E8-369F-BC36-27FF465809FD> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff9de5c000 -     0x7fff9de60ff7  libcache.dylib (79) <84E55656-FDA9-3B29-9E4F-BE31B2C0AA3C> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff9de61000 -     0x7fff9de6bfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60092.20.1) <31040F10-5E57-3B9C-8D5B-33AD87D1BEE8> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff9de6c000 -     0x7fff9de73fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (62) <486BDE52-81B4-3446-BD72-23977CAE556F> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff9de74000 -     0x7fff9de7cfff  libcopyfile.dylib (138) <0DA49B77-56EC-362D-98FF-FA78CFD986D6> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff9de7d000 -     0x7fff9defffdb  libcorecrypto.dylib (442.20.2) <2684CC01-087E-33E2-8219-AAA3BBD9BFD7> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff9df00000 -     0x7fff9df32fff  libdispatch.dylib (703.20.1) <877B505D-826C-3246-84F7-0F850636039E> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff9df33000 -     0x7fff9df38ff3  libdyld.dylib (421.2) <7BFA3476-6210-3BCB-8CE8-9B952F87BD84> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff9df39000 -     0x7fff9df39ffb  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <09CD7CA6-46D2-3A9F-B9F1-7C4CA5CA0D68> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff9df47000 -     0x7fff9df47fff  liblaunch.dylib (972.20.3) <7AB2E2EA-8B47-3420-87CE-5EE18A4EEE49> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff9df48000 -     0x7fff9df4dfff  libmacho.dylib (894) <1EAE5ADD-490C-3B1F-9F97-447BA8E0E90F> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff9df4e000 -     0x7fff9df50ff3  libquarantine.dylib (85) <F3E47D7C-8776-327C-9426-DD7DEB30DBDD> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff9df51000 -     0x7fff9df52ffb  libremovefile.dylib (45) <C4FC07FF-ED86-382E-B06F-33C34718080C> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff9df53000 -     0x7fff9df6bff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (349.1.1) <F0987490-8427-367F-B302-A05A7D61FEBF> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff9df6c000 -     0x7fff9df6cff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (67) <B8C3701D-5A91-3D35-999D-2DC8D5393525> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff9df6d000 -     0x7fff9dffafef  libsystem_c.dylib (1158.20.4) <5F9531F5-EDA3-3D25-A827-3E0FD6B392BA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff9dffb000 -     0x7fff9dffeffb  libsystem_configuration.dylib (888.20.5) <CDC55FCB-C1FC-350D-A919-5DBCFC835B63> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff9dfff000 -     0x7fff9e002fff  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (41.2) <5DE691C6-7EE6-3210-895D-9EA3ECBC09B4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff9e003000 -     0x7fff9e01bffb  libsystem_coretls.dylib (121.1.1) <8F7E9B12-400D-3276-A9C5-4546B0258554> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
    0x7fff9e01c000 -     0x7fff9e022fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (765.20.4) <28E52C39-DF10-340F-A3EC-C0119AF6361F> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff9e023000 -     0x7fff9e04cfff  libsystem_info.dylib (503) <C686B834-5E7D-382C-AF6E-44AB78EE83E2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff9e04d000 -     0x7fff9e06fff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (3789.21.3) <EC53F92A-0DFA-3027-A220-414A01F17B2E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff9e070000 -     0x7fff9e0b7fe7  libsystem_m.dylib (3121.4) <7F86C291-B105-31C1-9923-90EBAB22B73F> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff9e0b8000 -     0x7fff9e0d6ff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (116) <F9840080-4C2C-3F3B-8087-7C738F12A1C7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff9e0d7000 -     0x7fff9e12eff3  libsystem_network.dylib (856.20.4) <2BAFB24F-999C-3148-BDD8-F28E05F716F7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff9e12f000 -     0x7fff9e138ff3  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (563.20.3) <971DD3AD-D17A-32FF-95DE-0A5A979E68AE> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff9e139000 -     0x7fff9e142ff3  libsystem_notify.dylib (165.20.1) <EAD023A2-AD3F-31C8-9489-274B9A42DA61> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff9e143000 -     0x7fff9e14bfe7  libsystem_platform.dylib (126.1.2) <2F2D6A81-C36C-353D-B27B-A6643A32375E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff9e14c000 -     0x7fff9e156ff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (218.20.1) <46375095-4731-3034-9D87-396DE95FC697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff9e157000 -     0x7fff9e15aff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (592.21.2) <2D42A2BF-A7AF-352A-A821-D8F6E85A63AC> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff9e15b000 -     0x7fff9e15cfff  libsystem_secinit.dylib (24) <A54B8FEF-E792-3C54-8E0B-E80A376662F2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff9e15d000 -     0x7fff9e164fff  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (532.1.1) <8FB7CA37-79EF-3651-B5B9-B5E1E0947067> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
    0x7fff9e165000 -     0x7fff9e185ff7  libsystem_trace.dylib (518.20.8) <C029B910-A65F-35F6-B194-B933B454EAB4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff9e186000 -     0x7fff9e18bffb  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <9F7C2AD8-A9A7-3DE4-828D-B0F0F166AAA0> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff9e18c000 -     0x7fff9e1b5ff7  libxpc.dylib (972.20.3) <85EB25FD-218F-38EE-9E69-391CC8EBE6C5> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 5848
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=119.5M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=119.5M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=38.4M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=38.4M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
MALLOC                            30.2M       10 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        2 
Stack                             8192K        2 
VM_ALLOCATE                          4K        2 
__DATA                            1460K       43 
__LINKEDIT                       111.6M        4 
__TEXT                            8108K       42 
shared memory                       12K        4 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            215.1M      105 

Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B2C, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.69f3
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.1f7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: KINGSTON SH100S3480G, 480.1 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
```

Comment: It is very off-topic for [so]. It will be closed immediately. Can you clarify what app you are trying to launch?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251808/this-upx-compressed-binary-contains-an-invalid-mach-o-header-and-cannot-be-load